# Postgresql Query very slow with ::date, ::time, and interval

Tags: postgresql

I have a sql query that is very slow:

```
        select number1 from mytable
        where symbol = 25
        and timeframe = 1
        and date::date = '2008-02-05'
        and date::time='10:40:00' + INTERVAL '30 minutes'
```

The goal is to return one value, and postgresql takes 1.7 seconds to return the desired value(always a single value). I need to execute hundreds of those queries for one task, so this gets extremely slow.
Executing the same query, but pointing to the time directly without using interval and ::date, ::time takes only 17ms:

```
    select number1 from mytable
    where symbol = 25
    and timeframe = 1
    and date = '2008-02-05 11:10:00'
```

I thought it would be faster if I would not use ::date and ::time, but when I execute a query like:

```
    select number1 from mytable
    where symbol = 25
    and timeframe = 1
    and date = '2008-02-05 10:40:00' + interval '30 minutes'
```

I get a sql error (22007). I've experimented with different variations but I couldn't get interval to work without using ::date and ::time. Date/Time Functions on postgresql.org didn't help me out.

The table got a multi column index on symbol, timeframe, date.

Is there a fast way to execute the query with adding time, or a working syntax with interval where I do not have to use ::date and ::time? Or do I need to have a special index when using queries like these?

Postgresql version is 9.2.

Edit: 
The format of the table is:
date = timestamp with time zone,
symbol, timeframe = numeric.

Edit 2:
Using

```
select open from ohlc_dukascopy_bid
where symbol = 25
and timeframe = 1
and date = timestamp '2008-02-05 10:40:00' + interval '30' minute
```

Explain shows:

```
"Index Scan using mcbidindex on mytable  (cost=0.00..116.03 rows=1 width=7)"
"  Index Cond: ((symbol = 25) AND (timeframe = 1) AND (date = '2008-02-05 11:10:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
```

Time is now considerably faster: 86ms on first run.

Comment: And please post the full error message, not only the error number.

Comment: I only have an multi column index on symbol, timeframe, date. would an extra index exclusively for date make sense? I thought the multi column index would be enough. Edit: I see I should run a explain to see if my index is being used.

Comment: depends on how the index is defined. Which column is first in the index? Please post the full table definition including indexes and the execution plan

Comment: the index is on symbol, timeframe, date in that order, same order that the query is using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version will not use a (regular) index on the column named `date`.

You didn't provide much information, but assuming the column named `date` has the datatype  `timestamp` (and not `date`), then the following should work:

```
and date = timestamp '2008-02-05 10:40:00' + interval '30 minutes'
```

this should use an index on the column named `date` (but only if it is in fact a `timestamp` not a `date`). It is essentially the same as yours, the only difference is the explicit timestamp literal (although Postgres *should* understand `'2008-02-05 10:40:00'` as a timestamp literal as well).

You will need to run an `explain` to find out if it's using an index.

And please: change the name of that column. It's bad practise to use a reserved word as an identifier, and it's a really horrible name, which doesn't say anything about what kind of information is stored in the column. Is it the "start date", the "end date", the "due date", ...?

Comment: Works like a charm. Would give another +1 for the answer speed if I could. Would you mind taking a look at explain and tell me if its using the index as desired? I think it does but I'm not sure I am reading it right.

Comment: @harbun: yes it does use the index: *Index Scan using mcbidindex on mytable*